# Package javacardx.framework does not exist

Tags: javacard

Im new here and trying to develop a applet for Javacard. While following a sample code from a website, I get stuck here. NetBeans says the Package javacardx.framework does not exist.

Im using NetBeans 7.3.1

I would have not linked the Java Classic Jar file properly. Please help me

Comment: I only ever use Eclipse for javacard development. But seeing your error message, it seems that you have not added the JAR library containing javacardx. Try to download and include the library or use javacard plugin. For plugin, you can check https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/java-card.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot program against the standard Java API for Java Card. Java Card only uses (most of the) Java syntax and `.class` files as intermediate compilation results. Instead you need to configure the libraries of the Java Card SDK. Furthermore you need to run the Java Card converter, and for this you need the converted binaries and "export files" of those libraries.

More information can be found in the [Java Card Development Quickstart Guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/java-card.html) of the Java Card Netbeans plugin.

Comment: Something missing from my answer, GaneshMoorthy?